# Symfony2: Fill some fields of a form with post data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a contact form that works fine. But I want to fill some of this fields when an user click in one link. I receipt the information of some fields in the form controller, but I don't know how can I show this form with this fields with these datas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object, which corresponds to your data fields, when you create your form :

In your controller:

```
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

Or if you have your own FormType class, bind it to your Entity :

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Build form here
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        // Bind entity here
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BlueLinea\Bundle\BlueHomeCareBundle\Entity\MyEntity',
        ));
    }
}
```

And in your controller :

```
$myEntity = new MyEntity();
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $myEntity);
```

See [Forms (Building the Form) - Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I do this, the form try to submit alone, without user press "submit button", i want to show the form with this fields filled and other fields empty for user write it.